# How to change a lot of textview to scrolled list layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, layout, android-listview

I'm begginer in programming and i need your help. I have to write application which will be display sensor results as text, and i did it in wrong way (code is working, but when screen is not scrolling).

Below i copy XML file:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rLight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rPressure"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rLight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rHumidity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rPressure"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rProximity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rHumidity"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rTemp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rProximity"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rAccel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rTemp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rGyro"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rAccel"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rMag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rGyro"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rRotation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rMag"/>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rGravity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rRotation"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rSCounter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rGravity"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rSDetector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rSCounter"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rLinearAcc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rSDetector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rSignMotion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rLinearAcc"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rNoise"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rSignMotion"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

and this is main class:

*public class MainActivity extends Activity implements EventListener, StepCounterListener, LinearAccListener, StepDetectorListener, LightSensorListener, PressureSensorListener, GravitySensorListener, RotationVectorListener, RelativeHumidityListener, ProximitySensorListener, TempSensorListener, AccelerometerSensorListener, GyroSensorListener, MagSensorListener {*

```
private TextView lightText, pressureText, signText, noiseText, humidityText, linearAccText, proximityText, tempText, accelText, gyroText, magText, rotationText, gravityText, stepDetectorText, stepCounterText;
private LightSensor mLightSensor;
private PressureSensor mPressureSensor;
private RelativeHumiditySensor mRelativeHumidity;
private ProximitySensor mProximitySensor;
private TemperatureSensor mTempSensor;
private AccelerometerSensor mAccelSensor;    
private GyroscopeSensor mGyroSensor;
private MagnetometerSensor mMagSensor;
private RotationSensor mRotSensor;
private GravitySensor mGravitySensor;
private StepCounterSensor mStepCounter;
private StepDetectorSensor mStepDetector;
private LinearAccelerometer mLinearAcc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lightText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rLight);
    pressureText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rPressure);
    humidityText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rHumidity);
    proximityText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rProximity);
    tempText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rTemp);
    accelText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rAccel);
    gyroText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rGyro);
    magText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rMag);
    rotationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rRotation);
    gravityText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rGravity);
    stepCounterText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rSCounter);
    stepDetectorText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rSDetector);
    linearAccText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rLinearAcc);
    signText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rSignMotion);
    noiseText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rNoise);


    mLightSensor = new LightSensor(getBaseContext());
    mLightSensor.setListener(this);

    mPressureSensor = new PressureSensor(getBaseContext());
    mPressureSensor.setListener(this);

    mRelativeHumidity = new RelativeHumiditySensor(getBaseContext());
    mRelativeHumidity.setListener(this);

    mProximitySensor = new ProximitySensor(getBaseContext());
    mProximitySensor.setListener(this);

    mTempSensor = new TemperatureSensor(getBaseContext());
    mTempSensor.setListener((TempSensorListener) this);
    [...]

}


public void onLightSensorChanged(String lux){
    lightText.setText("LIGHT level: " + lux);
}

public void onPressureSensorChanged(String pressure){
    //items.add("PRESSURE: " + pressure);
    pressureText.setText("PRESSURE: " + pressure);
}
```

[...]

I tried use ArrayString, listAdapter but i had always a lot of errors.. please help

Comment: Use a ScrollView. Since the ScrollView can have only one direct child, you before need to wrap all the view in a group view (for example a LinearLayout) and then put this LinearLayout inside a ScrollView. A better solution is to use a ListView

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rLight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rPressure"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        .....................

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a scrollview , just insert your XML contents inside this before the  and it should work:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```